# Can I tell the Chrome script debugger to ignore jquery.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to tell the Chrome debugger (or maybe Firebug?) to not break within certain files? To assume they're not broken, essentially? This seems like something they might build in.

Comment: This would be particularly useful to me in the context of jquery events. When an event is triggered you have to step through a lot of crud to figure out which handlers are being invoked.

Comment: It looks you should mark jfriend00 as the answer. I could not find the reason for that annoying behavior, and his answer solved it up.

Comment: @OrPaz I disagree, my problem (and my understanding of Josh's problem) is that we are debugging our file, however this does not mean an exception is being thrown. My assumption is that my code is the problem and not jQuery's, so I never want to debug jQuery. I think of it like the DebuggerHiddenAttribute in .NET

Comment: I voted up jfriend00's answer, because it might be valuable to folks who come across this question, but I didn't mark it as the correct answer, because Nathan Koop is right, it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Blackboxing JS files is now possible in Firefox
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

And in Chrome Canary using Experimental Dev tools.
http://www.divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/ignoring-library-code-while-debugging-in-chrome/

***Update***. In Chrome v.*75* there is a separabe [tab for blackboxing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDx4v.jpg).

Above works in stable Chrome build as well now.

Comment: Blackboxing doesn't seem to make the debugger skip the file. It will still pass through it's function calls... Completely ignoring a file would be nice.

Comment: That is the point in blackboxing - running the code without seeing it's contents.

Comment: Isn't blackboxing when you simply don't step through the other libraries, not that they don't exist or aren't being used.

Comment: updated link for firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Black_box_a_source

Comment: Blackboxing has been [renamed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449405/14313852) to Ignore List in Chrome. Still FF Ignore list works better.

Answer (score 31):

The latest version of Chrome has implemented a new [blackbox feature](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing) that does exactly what you are looking for.  Basically, when you set the blackbox option on a given file, it will prevent Chrome debugger from breaking into that file.

This feature is built-in and it can be set with the context menu of the file (right click). It will also work if Chrome debugger is set for stopping on all exceptions.

Comment: very Clean solution No plugins needed.

Comment: No longer works unfortunately. 

If you have "Pause On Caught Exceptions" checked and then blackbox jQuery it will still break on the exceptions.

Comment: too bad it doesn't work well

Answer (score 16):

If the issue you're having is that the Chrome debugger is stopping on all exceptions, even the ones inside of jQuery, then you may need to tell Chrome to only pause on uncaught exceptions, not all exceptions.  When in the Script panel in the debugger, there is an icon in the lower left corner of the window that controls this.

Answer (score 14):

In Chrome, open Developer Tools, then goto Settings, and you will see the **Blackbox** tab:

[image: Chrome Blackbox]

In FireFox it's even easier, just click the Eye at the bottom of the file:

[image: FireFox Blackbox]

Comment: You just made my life heaven! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to developer tools setting and click on Balckboxing tab on the left panel.
2. Then click on the Add pattern button and type jquery.js
3. Close and reopen developer tools, now its skipped!

Answer (score 4):

You can follow this link to ignore the pattern in latest chrome browser (mine is : Version 100.0.4896.60 (Official Build)).

https://dilshankelsen.com/ignore-library-code-while-debugging-browser/

Developer Tools > Settings (Cog Icon) > Ignore List. Then add a file name or regex pattern you wish to exclude.

Answer (score 2):

If the debugger is blowing up somewhere in the jQuery files, you could potentially wrap the suspect calls in a try/catch and then throw an error in your own `catch`. That way, you can isolate exactly where your're going wrong.

I would be more inclined to do stack traces to see why my code is blowing up, e.g. invalid JSON, than to try gloss over it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Developer Tools** > **Settings** *(Cog Icon ⚙️)* > **Ignore List**.
Then add a **Custom exclusion rule** like file name or *regex pattern* of the library you want to exclude:

[image]