# Chrome Blackboxing with js Files Changeable Names

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I have a minified file in my project:

> `~/scripts/32e7c1e1ec06.vendor.js`

This file is minified and renamed with a new prefix code (`32e7c1e1ec06` part) for each project compilation.

I'm trying to use blackboxing as described in the links below:

- [Can I tell chrome script debugger to ignore jquery.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126822/can-i-tell-the-chrome-script-debugger-to-ignore-jquery-js)
- [Blackboxing React](https://denysdovhan.com/blackboxing-react/)

So far I came up with this:

(Chrome > F1 > Blackboxing > Blackbox content scripts > Pattern):

> `\*\-vendor\.js$`

But doesn't seems to work. When I debug my code and press F11, I keep hitting `32e7c1e1ec06-vendor.js` code.

How to fix it and force the blackboxing?

Comment: I'm not sure but if your pattern is a regex pattern it should be `.*\.vendor\.js$`

Comment: You're right. It works, please put this in a answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex seems to be incorrect. According to this:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing

You should be using a regex pattern like this:

```
.*\.vendor\.js$
```

Comment: I think actually it must be `.*\-vendor\.js$` for your case. but `.` will also work as the `-` before 'vendor' is also matched by `.` regex